# Why does "Germ" as Rvalue in declaration act as array object but as pointer elsewhere in assignment?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, declaration

Bear with me as I am adding some minor, secondary questions too instead of posting those separately

In a declaration `char name[]="Germ";` the identifier **Germ** is of type char[5], right? But in an assignment like `ptr="Germ"`, where **ptr** had been declared as a character pointer, "Germ" acts as a character pointer, right?

So here are my confusions which I request you to clear. Even one liners would be helpful:

1) Why is "Germ" an array object in declaration but a pointer in second? Should I conclude that a particular syntax has different meaning during declaration than in other statements? For example "{'a','b','c'}" is an initializer for an array and not a compound statement even though enclosed in curly brackets...

2) In the first declaration of this question, are "&name" and "name" of different types in that "&name" is the address of an array object of size 5 while "name" is the address of a character variable, i.e, the address of the first element of the array called **name**? I feel it is so, but want your confirmation.

3) And finally, if modifying strings is UB in C (I read in a good book), how come the following code doesn't show even a warning and prints **"ariund"**?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char str[]="around";
str[2]='i';
printf("%s",str);
return 0;
}
```

You answers will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Modifying string literal is invalid but for case `char str[]="around";` it's valid. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703720/i-feel-confusion-about-bus-error-in-string-c/22703925#22703925)

Comment: It is not an assignment; it is an initializer for the array. `str` is the name of an array. The array lives in automatic storage.

Comment: @Jayesh umm, in simple and precise terms, how you define a "string literal"? The identifier of the string?

Comment: `ptr="Germ"` is assignment make ptr point to string literal which is constant string and it's placed in read only parts.

Comment: @user3121023 Oops, typo. Corrected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it might help you to understand some of the issues...

---

Given the following function:

```
void func()
{
    char  arr[] = "RW";
    char* ptr   = "RO";
}
```

During the build process, **both** strings are hard-coded into a **read-only** section of the executable image.

During runtime, every time the function is called:

- The content of the `"RW\0"` string is copied into the stack (i.e., into `arr`)
- The address of the `"RO\0"` string is copied into the stack (i.e., into `ptr`)

At this point, since you have a copy of the `"RW\0"` string, you can change the contents of that copy.

You cannot change either one of the original strings, as they both reside in a  read-only memory section.

---

**A few notable differences between arrays and pointers:**

With `int arr[10]`:

- Amount of memory used is `sizeof(int)*10` bytes
- The values of `arr` and `&arr` are necessarily identical
- `arr` points to a valid memory address, but cannot be set to point to another memory address

With `int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*10)`:

- Amount of memory used is `sizeof(int*) + sizeof(int)*10` bytes
- The values of `ptr` and `&ptr` are not necessarily identical (in fact, they are mostly different)
- `ptr` can be set to point to both valid and invalid memory addresses, as many times as you will

Comment: You are very close to what I wanted the answer for. Can you please give me an example of a statement that attempts to change either of the original strings?

Comment: Your update was very much helpful, but I still couldn't gather an answer for what I asked in the above comment. Can you please give a simple example of statements that attempt to change either of the original strings you illustrated?Please...

Comment: @Meathead: In order to change the contents of the original `"RO\0"` string pointed by `ptr`, you can simply do something like `ptr[0] = 'k'`. Of course, that will result with a memory access violation during runtime.

Comment: Thank you. It answers my question exactly.

Comment: @Meathead: You're welcome, feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)

Comment: I would have irrespective :-). I give it some hours just in case other whiz like you has something more to add. Anyways, accepting immediately for you!!